# What can make btrfs device replace fail silently?

Tags: linux, raid, btrfs

In a performance-critical system, we run Btrfs RAID0. We have three devices relevant to this question:

- `/dev/sda2`, an SSD that is too small and slow, and limits the size and overall performance of the system.
- `/dev/sdb`, actually multiple drives in a hardware RAID0 configuration, seen as one in software.
- `/dev/sdc`, identical to `/dev/sdb`, but not currently part of the Btrfs system.

To get the performance and size we want, we are replacing /dev/sda2 with /dev/sdc:

```
btrfs replace start /dev/sda2 /dev/sdc /
btrfs replace status /
```

Checking the status of this, we get `2.3% done, 0 write errs, 0 uncorr. read errs` and counting, but it cancels without errors at random points. 34.7% is as far as we have gotten. The status reverts to 0.0%: `Started on 31.Aug 22:31:17, canceled on 31.Aug 22:43:28 at 0.0%, 0 write errs, 0 uncorr. read errs`. Similarly, there is absolutely nothing added to `dmesg`.

```
$ uname -sr
Linux 5.5.11-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

---

*Addendum:*

It *looks* like we get further with more available space on the current volumes. We're at 20% free space now, and got all the way to 75.0% done before it failed. It could be a red herring, though.

```
$ btrfs filesystem usage /
Overall:
    Device size:                   4.33TiB
    Device allocated:              1.06TiB
    Device unallocated:            3.27TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                        841.52GiB
    Free (estimated):              3.50TiB      (min: 1.86TiB)
    Data ratio:                       1.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)

Data,RAID0: Size:1.01TiB, Used:802.82GiB
   /dev/sda2     517.00GiB
   /dev/sdb      517.00GiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:24.19GiB, Used:19.35GiB
   /dev/sda2      24.19GiB
   /dev/sdb       24.19GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:112.00KiB
   /dev/sda2      32.00MiB
   /dev/sdb       32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sda2       1.00MiB
   /dev/sdb        2.75TiB
```

Comment: Update: At 300 GiB used out of 1 TiB total, we got to 98.8%...